# Writing a continuous function of bounded variation as the sum of a singular function and an absolutely continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis

A function $\varphi[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be singular if

1. $\varphi \in C[a,b]$ (i.e., $\varphi$ is continuous on $[a,b]$),
2. $\varphi'(x)$ exists a.e. in $[a,b]$,
3. $\varphi'(x)=0$ a.e. in $[a,b]$.

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and of bounded variation on $[a,b]$.
Prove that there is an absolutely continuous function 
$F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and a singular function 
$\varphi: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = F + \varphi$.

Comment: It is true for a monotone increasing function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534622/monotone-increasing-function-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-absolutely-continuous-fu)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function of bounded variation is  a difference of two monotone increasing functions. Just note that linear combinations of absolutely continuous functions are absolutely continuous  and linear combinations of singular continuous functions are singular.