# Construct martingale with given quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes

This question is from Protter's Stochastic calculus Problem 4 chapter 2.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be non-decreasing and continuous. Show that there exists continuous martingale $M$ such that $[M,M]_t=f(t)$

I only know how to show this when $f$ is absolute continuous. Suppose $f$ is absolute continuous, there exists $g\in L^1$ such that $f=\int_0^t g\ dt$. Then define $M$ as ($B_t$ is a Brownian motion)
\begin{align*}
M = \sqrt{g}\cdot B_t= \int_0^t \sqrt{g}\ dB_t
\end{align*}
By the property of quadratic variation
\begin{align*}
[M,M] = \int_0^t g \ dt = f(t)
\end{align*}
However, for the general $f$, I am not sure how to proceed. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534622/monotone-increasing-function-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-absolutely-continuous-fu) should help.

Comment: @KurtG. The singular part is hard to deal with. Being differentiable does not imply the function is an anti-derivative of another function.

Comment: In addition to that link you assume with Protter that $f$ is also continuous. So I think that in your case there should be no singular part.