Show that $\int_a^bF(x)dx+\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}dy=bF(b)-aF(a)$
Problem. Suppose $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ and $F:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is strictly increasing and continuous. Prove that
$$\int_a^bF(x)dx+\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}(y)dy=bF(b)-aF(a).$$

Attempt. Consider $$\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}(y)dy=\int_a^b xF'(x)dx$$
using the result that $$\int (g{\small\circ} F)(x)|F'(x)|dx=\int g(y)dy$$
if $F$ is a bijection and a continuously differentiable function.
However, $F$ needs to be differentiable a.e. and $F'$ continuous. If $F$ has a "sharp" edge (change in derivative making $F'$ not defined everywhere) it still satisfies all conditions mentioned in the question but the method is no more valid. Moreover, this may be occur at countably many points.

How do I solve this? [Note that the above are Lebesgue integrals.]
Update. In the link mentioned in the comments, they have assumed that we can only have finitely many partitions to address when $F'$ doesn't exist. What justifies that?

Not sure what you are asking.  We are told that $F$ is strictly increasing and that it is continuous, that means that it is bijective onto its image.

@lulu You're right. I misframed my question. Have updated it

I think this is easier if you consider the graphical interpretation of the sum of the two integrals.

Should that be $F^{-1}(y)dy$?

@SaiMehta The graphical interpretation don't help much to give a formal proof, does it?

@reyna For $[a,b]$, the Riemann integral is the same as  Lebesgue integral!$$(R)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=(L)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$$

@jjagmath no it is not very formal.

Your initial idea is good, we can use a substitution with Lebesgue integrals in the following, if $g \colon X \to Y$ is a measurable bijection, then (you can prove this for characteristic functions and then extend to simple functions by linearity and then use the standard approximation argument):
$$
\int_{X} f(g(x)) \ d\mu(x) = \int_{Y} f(y) \ d(\mu\circ g^{-1})(y).
$$
So back to your case, if $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, since $F$ is strictly monotone, so is $F^{-1}$ and then both are absolutely continuous (hence differentiable a.e., with derivative integrable and satisfying fundamental theorem of calculus)
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b} F^{-1}(F(x)) F'(F^{-1}(F(x))) \ dx &= \int_{F(a)}^{F(b)} F^{-1}(y) F'(y)\ d(m\circ F^{-1})(y) \\ 
&= \int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}(y)F'(F^{-1}(y))(F^{-1})'(y) \ dy.
\end{align*}
Since they are differentiable a.e., standard calculus show that $F'(F^{-1}(y))(F^{-1})'(y) = 1$ a.e., hence the equality above is
$$
\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}(y) \ dy = \int_{a}^{b} xF'(x) \ dx.
$$
Now, since $F$ and $h(x) = x$ are absolutely continuous, we can use integration by parts, so we have
$$
\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}F^{-1}(y) \ dy = xF(x)\Biggr|_{a^{+}}^{b^{-}} - \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \ dx = bF(b) - aF(a) - \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \ dx,
$$
which is what we wanted.

@reyna see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534622/monotone-increasing-function-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-absolutely-continuous-fu also, differentiability a.e. is not sufficient, it must also be absolutely continuous

I’m not sure if you find it useful, but let $a,b\gt 0$ and $F(x)\gt0$ for any $x$, for the sake of simplicity.
Then, since $F$ is strictly increasing and continuous, $$\int_a^b F(x)\,dx$$ is area “beneath” the graph, and $$\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)} F^{-1}(y)\,dy$$ is area “to the left” of the graph. Their sum is the difference of areas of two rectangles, so is equal to $$b\cdot F(b)-a\cdot F(a).$$

We're dealing with lebesgue integrals. I was looking for a measure-theoretical approach

This is a nice geometric interpretation, but not a proof. So it should probably be a comment, not an answer.

it can be turned easily into a proof
